# Logic behind this rearranging of summation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, vectors

In eigenchrises video "Tensors for Beginners 1: Forward and Backward Transformations (contains error; read description!)" , at around time $6.41$ , There is a rearranging of summations I seem to not understand.[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdCmW5N1LW4&t=474s)

Around that time , there was this summation:

$$\vec e_i = \sum_j B_{ij} \sum_k F_{jk} \vec e_k$$

My question is , how he was able to arrange the summations like this:

$$\vec e_i = \sum_k \sum_j (B_{ij}  F_{jk}) \vec e_k$$

I don't know much about summations , so I am probably missing something trivial.Also , can someone tell me about a book where I can learn about this kind of summation algebra? (I couldn't find a book which has the explanation for this arrangement)

Comment: It might help if you actually write the terms out, and you can rearrange them to see the pattern. There's not really a summation law being used here.

Comment: They use two things: $c\sum_n a_n = \sum_n ca_n$, which just generalises $c(a+b) = ca+cb$. (in your case $B_{ij}$ doesn't depend on $k$, so it is a constant from the point of view of the $k$-sum). And then they swap $\sum_j\sum_k=\sum_k\sum_j$. This might be surprising when you first see it, but try writing out $\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3 a_{jk}$, and you'll see it's okay to swap.